# How to hold particular url key from .json file based on the value given in the function parameter

Tags: c#, restsharp

API Testing using RestSharp

I have added config.json file and maintaining all the URL in the file.
Example

```json
{
   "Url1": "http://localhost:45677",
   "Url2": "http://localhost:45897"
}
```

I would like to fetch particular URL from the config.json based on the given parameter added in class2

```cs
public class class2
{
    public void Url1_Request()
    {
        var client = class1.RestClient("Url1");
    }
    public void Url2_Request()
    {
        var client = class1.RestClient("Url2");
    }
}


public class class1
{
    public static RestClient RestClient(string url)
    {

        var client = new RestClient(url);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.....

public static RestClient restClient()
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\...\config.json"))
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
        
    var jsonObject=JObject.Parse(json);
    
    var url=GetUrl(jsonObject,"Url1");
   return new RestClient(url);
}
    
public string GetUrl(JObject jsonObject, string url)
{
    return  (string) jsonObject[url];
}
```

url

```
http://localhost:45677
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the .json file to object. If you don't have some build in function for it, you can use some third party library. Some example is described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

May be you need to change structure of .json file to Dictionary or array